# Rails testing duplicates error message for all failed tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

Whenever I run `rails test` it's duplicating the error messages for every single different failed test.

```
2019-12-10 21:22:28 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
Run options: --seed 19059

# Running:

E

Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_comment:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:28.988662', '2019-12-10 21:22:28.988662', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:41

E

Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.368082', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.368082', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:31

E

Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_show_comment:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.438270', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.438270', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:26

E

Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_create_comment:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.537555', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.537555', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:18

E

Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.590334', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.590334', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:13

E

Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.641851', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.641851', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:8

E

Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_update_comment:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.694643', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.694643', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:36

E

Error:
EchosControllerTest#test_should_create_echo:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.746984', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.746984', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/echos_controller_test.rb:18

E

Error:
EchosControllerTest#test_should_destroy_echo:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.809118', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.809118', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/echos_controller_test.rb:41

E

Error:
EchosControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.877797', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.877797', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/echos_controller_test.rb:31

E

Error:
EchosControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.939092', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.939092', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/echos_controller_test.rb:13

E

Error:
EchosControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:29.995686', '2019-12-10 21:22:29.995686', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/echos_controller_test.rb:8

E

Error:
EchosControllerTest#test_should_show_echo:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:30.050512', '2019-12-10 21:22:30.050512', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/echos_controller_test.rb:26

E

Error:
EchosControllerTest#test_should_update_echo:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-12-10 21:22:30.103160', '2019-12-10 21:22:30.103160', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/echos_controller_test.rb:36
```

The same  `UNIQUE constraint failed` message appears for all 14 errors in my tests. I thought fixing the Unique constraint failure might change the error messages to some other type, but I tried `rails db:reset` and the duplicated messages persist.

Here are my echos_controller and comments_controller classes:

```
class EchosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_echo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /echos
  # GET /echos.json
  def index
    @echos = Echo.all
  end

  # GET /echos/1
  # GET /echos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /echos/new
  def new
    @echo = current_user.echos.build
  end

  # GET /echos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /echos
  # POST /echos.json
  def create
    @echo = current_user.echos.build(echo_params) 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @echo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @echo, notice: 'Echoed succesfully' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @echo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @echo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /echos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /echos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @echo.update(echo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @echo, notice: 'Echo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @echo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @echo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /echos/1
  # DELETE /echos/1.json
  def destroy
    @echo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to echos_url, notice: 'Echo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def upvote
    @echo = Echo.find(params[:id])
    @echo.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end

  def downvote
    @echo = Echo.find(params[:id])
    @echo.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_echo
      @echo = Echo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def echo_params
      params.require(:echo).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

---

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  #def edit
  #end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @echo = Echo.find(params[:echo_id])
    @comment = @echo.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @echo, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:echo_id, :body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: show the part of your test that creates those users

Comment: It looks like you are not setting an email and you don't have a validation for email presence so all users are valid, activerecord tries to save them with empty email and the database raises the uniqueness error.

Comment: Could the error be caused by bad fixtures?